# Using Zend Framework w/o installing it in server root?

Tags: php, zend-framework, installation

I am trying to use Zend's Gbase library, but I cannot figure out how to do so without actually installing it in the PHP path.

The complication comes from wanting to make a module for Drupal that is not constrained by the server it is installed on, but can access the library by having it installed in a subfolder of the module.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I have tried doing an include of Zend's Loader and then loading the classes I want, but this keeps throwing errors.  Do I NEED to install the library on the server, or is there a way around this, to only have it used on this application?

This is the code:

```
require_once 'library/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gbase');
```

I get the folowing messages:

Warning: Zend_Loader::include(Zend/Gdata/Gbase.php) [zend-loader.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/ftp-www/tests/gdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 83

Warning: Zend_Loader::include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Zend/Gdata/Gbase.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/www/ftp-www/tests/gdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 83

Warning: Zend_Loader::require_once(Zend/Exception.php) [zend-loader.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www/ftp-www/tests/gdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 87

Fatal error: Zend_Loader::require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /srv/www/ftp-www/tests/gdata/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 87

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using [set_include_path](http://php.net/set_include_path) to configure your [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), adding to it the directory in which Zend Framework's code is ?

This way, you can have it whereever you want -- whitout having to modify the `include_path` in the php.ini configuration file.

For instance, something like this might do :

```
$path = '/PATH_TO_THE_FRAMEWORK/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Wouldn't that help ?

Comment: Zend suggest to setup path so that the ZF path is in the beginning. Because it takes then less time to find the classes. Most classes are from ZF and few are your own...

Comment: thanks.  That seems to have worked.  Simply adding the 'library' to the zend_loader function wasn't enough.  Much appreciated.  

i'd vote up your answer, but I don't have enough 'reputation'

Comment: You're welcome :-) (don't worry about the rep thing ; still, if an answer solved your problem, you should be able to mark is as "accepted" -- you can do that on only one answer per question, though ; so, choose wisely ^^ )

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify where to look for the class files. Try:

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Gbase', 'library/')
```

Or you may want to set the library folder in your php include path